# Atualização PHP 7.4 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string

Tags: php

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou atualizando um sistema do PHP 5.6 para o 7.4 todavia sou programador iniciante e não fui eu quem desenvolvi o código.

Ao atualizar estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Users\ti\Documents\xxx-portal\views\template\view.php on line 57

Notice: Undefined property: ConteudoSiteControl::$Array in C:\Users\ti\Documents\xxx-portal\views\template\view.php on line 57

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\Users\ti\Documents\xxxx-portal\views\template\view.php on line 57

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in C:\Users\ti\Documents\xxx-portal\views\template\view.php:57 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\ti\Documents\xxx-portal\library\Loader.php(228): include() #1 C:\Users\ti\Documents\xxx-portal\index.php(111): Loader->redirecionar() #2 {main} thrown in C:\Users\ti\Documents\xxx-portal\views\template\view.php on line 57
```

todos na página views\template\view.php, já pesquisei muito sobre os erros na internet mas não consigo enxergar como corrigir os problemas na página, já tentei várias coisas.
O código da página é:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['pag'])) {

        $pagina = new Loader($_GET['pag']);

        if(!strstr($_GET['pag'], '/')){ 

            $controller = $pagina->getControllerPage();

            // CASO SEJA UTILIZADO O NOME ORIGINAL DO MÓDULO, SE FAZ NECESSÁRIO O TRATAMENTO
            // PARA INCLUIR O NOME DO CONTROLLER NA MESMA ESTRUTURA QUE É INSERIDO O CONTROLLER 
            // DE UMA PÁGINA COM NICKNAME
            if(!isset($controller['controller'])){

                $auxController            = $controller;
                $controller               = array();
                $controller['controller'] = $auxController;
            }

            $classe =  ucfirst($controller['controller'])."Control";

            if(class_exists($classe)){                            
                $objeto = new $classe();
                $loadView = $objeto->index();
            }else{
                errorPage(ERROR_CLASS_NOT_FOUND);
            }

        }else{

            $controller = $pagina->getControllerPage(true);
            $classe =  ucfirst($controller['controller'])."Control";

            if(class_exists($classe)){

                $objeto = new $classe();

                if(method_exists($objeto, $controller['acao'])){

                    if(!isset($controller['id'])){

                        $loadAction = $objeto->$controller['acao']();
                    }else{

                        if(isset($controller['pagina'])){

                            if(isset($controller['adicional'])){

                                $loadAction = $objeto->$controller['acao']($controller['id'], $controller['pagina'], $controller['adicional']);
                            }else{

                                $loadAction = $objeto->$controller['acao']($controller['id'], $controller['pagina']);
                            }
                        }else{

                            $loadAction = $objeto->$controller['acao']($controller['id']);
                        }
                    }
                }else{

                    errorPage(ERROR_METHOD_ACTION);
                }
            }else{

               errorPage(ERROR_CLASS_NOT_FOUND);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz? Já estou a algumas horas encima desse problema...

Comment: O que tem na linha 57 ? De qualquer forma você tem várias chamadas a métodos com nome dinamico, como por exemplo em `$objeto->$controller['acao']($controller['id']);` Se esse `$controller['acao']` não der um nome de um método que exista em `$objeto` então vai dar esse erro que você vê.

Comment: @Isac tem $loadAction = $objeto->$controller['acao']($controller['id']);

Comment: Antes de atualizar o PHP esse erro era inexistente, rodava dessa forma, eu não faço ideia de oque fazer para corrigir.

Comment: Isso significa que `$controller['acao']` gera um nome que não existe. Imagine que esse bloco de código se traduz no nome `verProduto`, então a instrução vai ficar`$objeto->verProduto(2)` em que `verProduto` não existe no `$objeto`. Tem de confirmar o valor que isso dá no código, que pode fazer com `var_dump` por exemplo. Não lhe sei dizer porque motivo esse código não dava erro na versão anterior do PHP, mas tem havido situações em que o PHP ficou menos permissivo com o avançar das versões. Pode ser que isso seja mais um caso.

Comment: pelo que entendi da primeira linha de de erro você está acessando um array como se fosse uma string daí o erro. nessa linha $objeto->$controller['acao']($controller['id'], $controller['pagina'], $controller['adicional']); 
Lógico que estou pressupondo isso com base no trecho de código que você disponibilizou.
Essa parte do array é uma função? pois quando você acessa  usando -> que dizer ou que é um método ou um atributo.